# Get Data from JSONPath and Compare Values with UI using Cypress

Tags: cypress, response, jsonpath, cypress-intercept

I'm trying to compare that values from UI are matched with json coming from the API response, using JSONPath in a Cypress test.

I want to get iPhone (refer Evaluation Result box) and want to compare it with the UI
[image]

Here's my test

```js
cy.intercept('https://jsonpath.com/').as('test');
 cy.visit('/');
     
 var jp = require('jsonpath');
 var names = jp.query('@test', '$.phoneNumbers[:1].type');  
 cy.get('@test').should((response) => {
 cy.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

The error I am getting is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [homepage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) says this is a Node package, so put it in a task

```js
//cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const jp = require('jsonpath');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      on('task', {
        jpquery: ({data, query}) => jp.query(data, query),
      })
    },
  },
})
```

Then the example given on the homepage would be tested this way -

```js
const cities = [
  { name: "London", "population": 8615246 },
  { name: "Berlin", "population": 3517424 },
  { name: "Madrid", "population": 3165235 },
  { name: "Rome",   "population": 2870528 }
];

cy.task('jpquery', { data: cities, query: '$..name' })
  .should('deep.eq', ['London', 'Berlin', 'Madrid', 'Rome'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of the commands, to start with. Then check what the `response` actually is before passing it to `jp.query()`.

The object you pass should be, well, an object.

```js
const jp = require('jsonpath');

cy.intercept('https://jsonpath.com/').as('test');
cy.visit('/');
     
cy.wait('@test').then((response) => {
  const phoneNoTypes = jp.query(response, '$.phoneNumbers[:1].type');  
  console.log(phoneNoTypes)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the object with JSON.parse.

```js
    cy.get('@test').then((test) => {
      const body = JSON.stringify(test)
      const json = JSON.parse(body)
      const bodyForJp = jp.query(json, "$.phoneNumbers[:1].type");
    })
```